# Git fetch only open PRs from Github

Tags: git

I wanted to be able to fetch the PRs form github, but discard the ones that are not open (either merged or closed without merging).

There are, as far as I know, two refs that I can fetch from github, for a given pr: head and merge. The first is the pr branch head, the second is the tip that master would have after the pr is merged in. The second one is present only for open PRs, it appears, so that was my first guess:

```
fetch +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/$rem/all-pr/*
fetch +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/$rem/open-pr/*
```

Then delete all refs in all-pr that are not also in open-pr. There is a catch though, I think. If git cannot perform an automatic merge of the PR, then there is no `refs/pull/X/merge` ref for pr number X. I assume this is the case, cause on some repo I have a pr (407) for which `refs/pull/407/head` exists, but `refs/pull/407/merge` does not exist. Therefore my first guess, albeit reasonable, is not always working.

So my question is: is there a way to write a small script that fetches all prs, discarding the ones not open, that works also in this corner case?

Note: I do not want to checkout a specific pr branch. I want to fetch *all* open PR refs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [the GitHub cli](https://cli.github.com/), with its [`gh pr list` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list)

```
gh pr list -s open
```

That would list only all open PR.

Comment: Good solution. And then I'm assuming you suggest to have a git alias (or bash alias, whatever), that does the fetch (and possibly checkout) of the pr branch. I think that's reasonable.

Comment: @bartgol I had. Although a [`gh pr checkout`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout) would do the fetch for you.